# Controlling keyboard LED lights using C

Tags: c

I want to create a program to represent binary numbers using the keyboard's LEDs. How can I control those LED lights using the C language?

Comment: Language does not matter that much, operating system is more important. Which operating system?

Comment: Are you using a PC ? Then read about port programming.

Comment: @shan: Port programming? Operating systems won't let you touch those these days!

Answer (score 2):

For Linux, this would be helpful

[setleds](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setleds)

A more comprehensive internals and several command line utilities description

[Keyboard and console - HowTo.pdf](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

For [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows):

> Because the SetKeyboardState function alters the input state of the calling thread and not the global input state of the system, an application cannot use SetKeyboardState to set the NUM LOCK, CAPS LOCK, or SCROLL LOCK (or the Japanese KANA) indicator lights on the keyboard. These can be set or cleared using SendInput to simulate keystrokes.

See the [Windows API ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).